# JavascriptExecutor error on trying to scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Below is the snippet and getting error as follows :

```
The method executeScript(String, Object[]) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Code Snippet :

```
public class ScrollPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumWorkSpace\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.out.println(driver);

        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        js.executeScript("scroll(0,2500)");

    }
}
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it without casting

```
driver.executeScript("scroll(0,2500)");
```

Comment: Even this din't help.. As driver isn't invoking or includes any executeScript method..

Answer (score 0):

Edit the line of code as :

```
//import
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
//cast driver instance to JavascriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//invove executeScript method    
js.executeScript("scroll(0, 2500)");
```

> **Note** : Put a space between the coordinates

Comment: No luck @DebanjanB

Comment: Can you update the Question with your full code block along with the imports and the full error stack trace?

Comment: For line "js.executeScript("scroll(0, 2500)");" i'm getting error stating "The method executeScript(String, Object[]) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,2500);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following - I was having the same error with JavascriptExecutor not performing scroll downs properly.

```
public WebElement pollingScroll(By locator) {
    WebDriverWait shortWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
    WebElement element = null;
    while(element == null) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 555);");
        try {
            element = 
            shortWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    return element;
}
```